# Difference between "little" and "small"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Is there any obvious difference between *little* and *small*?

A couple of examples:

> - Big car vs. *small* (or *little*) car
> - You have to pay just a *small* (or *little*) amount for such a wonderful item

Can I use those words interchangeably or are there any rules allowing only one of the words?

Comment: relevant xkcd https://xkcd.com/2122/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated by [narx's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31287/2637) to a similar question on ELU (English Language & Usage, ELL's "sister site" aimed primarily at linguists, etymologists, and *serious* English language enthusiasts), only ***little*** can be used as an unqualified noun to mean *a small amount* (where adjectival ***small*** needs an explicit noun, such as *amount* or *quantity*).

The other interesting point made about ***little*** there is that in...

> 1: *I have **a little** experience teaching English.*
> 2: *I have **little** experience teaching English.*

...the two sentences have almost opposite meanings - #1 implies you have *at least some* experience, whereas #2 implies *very little* (perhaps almost none). In fact, #1 is often used somewhat facetiously to imply you actually have *a lot* of whatever is being spoken of.

---

Apart from the above distinctions, there's also (as kiamlaluno points out) the fact that ***little*** often carries more "affectionate" connotations than ***small***. And from [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv339.shtml), ***little*** is more common in the sense *not much* when coupled with abstract nouns such as *hope, chance, change, effect, use* and *point*.

In most other contexts, there's little to choose between the two words. Use whichever you like.

Answer (score 5):

*Little* can be used to refer to something that is small in size, amount, or degree, but it is also used as affectionate way. *little puppy dog* doesn't necessarily mean the puppy is small.
When it is used for people, *little* could also mean *younger*, as in *my little brother*.

Comment: As for _little_ meaning _younger_, the oldest of my three daughters is also the shortest. When her younger sister passed her in height, we started a family quip: "Rachel has two little sisters... and so does Elizabeth."

Comment: The word "little" modifies "puppy dog", it means exactly that the puppy is particularly small, unless it is said jokingly of a Great Dane or Doberman.  In the phrase "**little old man**", it can either mean the elderly man is short in stature or it is an insult ***You little old man*** suggesting that the person is insignificant or contemptible.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answers of FumbleFingers and apaderno (kiamlaluno), it's worth noting those instances when *little* is used to denote a personality trait.

- *little/small dog*

In this example the adjectives “little” and “small” are interchangeable, they modify the noun *dog*. It means the dog is particularly small, unless it is said jokingly of a Great Dane or Doberman.

- *little/small boy(s)*
- *little/small girl(s)*
- *little/small children*

These examples invariably refer to *young* children but in the following cases, the meaning changes, and quite significantly too

- *little old man*

In the common expression "little old man", we are referring to either an elderly man who is short in stature, e.g. “He was a little old man who lived alone” or as an insult, e.g  “You *little* old man” suggesting that the person (who could even be middle-aged) is insignificant and contemptible.

- *[the little man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20little%20man#:%7E:text=chiefly%20US%2C%20informal,friend%20of%20the%20little%20man)*

This expression – note the obligatory definite article – is often used in the US and refers to the common person, the everyman who has *little* (it's never small!) political power or status.

- *small man*

Depending on context, it can either suggest that the man is small in height and build or his position and role in life is trivial, e.g ”He's just a small man in a [small business](https://www.yourdictionary.com/small-business).”

- *little old lady*

On the other hand, the expression *little old lady* evokes an elderly sometimes frail woman, who might even have a cheerful disposition, e.g. "She was a sweet little old lady”.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small%20old%20woman%2Csmall%20old%20lady%2Clittle%20old%20woman%2Clittle%20old%20lady&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmall%20old%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmall%20old%20lady%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clittle%20old%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clittle%20old%20lady%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csmall%20old%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmall%20old%20lady%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clittle%20old%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clittle%20old%20lady%3B%2Cc0) shows that the expression "little old lady” is far more common in print than its equivalent "little old woman” or when "little" is switched with "small”.

[image]

In the end, the choice between *small* and *little* often depends on context.